# Why __iter__ is returning self?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, iterable

all **iter** is doing is returning self. How does that turn an instance(numbers) of a class(PowTwo) into iterable?

```
class PowTwo:

def __init__(self, max=0):
    self.max = max

def __iter__(self):
    self.n = 0
    return self

def __next__(self):
    if self.n <= self.max:
        result = 2 ** self.n
        self.n += 1
        return result
    else:
        raise StopIteration


numbers = PowTwo(3)

i = iter(numbers)

print(next(i))
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
```

Comment: That's a really bad way to write an iterable, by the way - you'll see it in some terrible tutorials, but never do it yourself.

Comment: `__iter__` should never be mutative.

Comment: @HussamAhmed To cite the documentation of [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__): "Return the iterator object itself. This is required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the `for` and `in` statements."